# WAMP & PHP - Accessing a file on your desktop

Tags: php, windows, system, exec, wamp

We are using WAMP on our Dedicated Windows Server and basically, we have WAMP installed in the  regular location "C:\wamp\www". We have a file .json file that we want to access and decode, but I don't know how to access it from the current location?

We have tried this:

```
$variable = exec("cat C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\folder here\\players.json");
echo $variable;
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying you want to get the contents of that file? `file_get_contents()` would suffice surely? No need to execute a shell command

Answer (score 0):

I'd include some logic to check that the file exists:

```
$path = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\folder here\\players.json';

if (file_exists($path)) {
  $exec = exec("cat $path");
  var_dump($exec);
} else {
  echo 'File does not exist';
}
```

This will allow you to figure out whether the path is right. If you don't receive the error, you know something is wrong with your exec command.

Comment: See I tried doing that but nothing actually echo's. Each time I put a logical nothing is echoing like it doesn't exist? So strange..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read what's in the file:

```
$path = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\folder here\\players.json';

if (file_exists($path)) {
    $content = file_get_contents($path);
    echo $content;
} else {
    echo 'File does not exist';
}
```